PIL cannot identify specific JPG file
It works with other JPGs but not this one specifically, I'm wondering what's wrong and how it could be improved.
import io
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from PIL import Image

session = ClientSession

async with session.get(f'https://rocket-league.com/content/media/itemshopPreviewDetailed/2024-12-12.jpg') as r:
    if r.status == 200:
        try:
            img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(await r.read()))
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(e)

The error is:
WARNING: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f216a624810>.

what is self.bot.session.get()? are you sure r.read() whatever that is returns a complete data and not say just the first n-bytes?

The error message implies a corrupted file.  The URL works in the browser, I assume it does for you too.  Your code sample is incomplete though, what is session?

@MarkRansom @JonSG sorry, I edited; session is from aiohttp. Yes, the file works in my browser, and the code works with other JPGs, just not this one specifically. I assume there is something specific about this JPG file but I would like if possible to find a way to still make it work into an Image object with PIL since it's clearly an image.

Your code sample still isn't even close to a running example, I'd suggest you fix it.
